# Double values to create percentage values on Textviews

Tags: java, android, double, number-formatting

My code to update my Textviews. I want to update one of my textview's strings to show the percentage correctly. Right now `totalDouble` returns the correct value but I cannot multiply or divide the value. Any help is appreciated.

```
private static Integer intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted; 

protected void updateTheDailyandTotalUsageInformation(String string) {

    int daySelected = Integer.parseInt(string); //getting the day as a string

    //converting the series array to type Number
    Number dailyNumber = series2Numbers[daySelected-1]; 
    Number totalNumber = series1Numbers[daySelected-1];


    //converting the type Number to type Double
    Double dailyDouble =  (Double) dailyNumber;
    Double totalDouble = (Double) totalNumber;

    String dailyString = String.format("%.2f", dailyDouble);
    String totalString = String.format("%.2f", totalDouble);



    if(intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted >=1) { 
        System.out.println(totalDouble);

        // **Inside this if statement I want to do
        // (totalDouble/intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted) * 100
        // to create a percentage**

     // **I want to create something like this**
     // Double doublePercent = (totalDouble/(double)intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted) *100;
     // String percent =  doublePercent+"%";
     //usagePlanPercentTextView.setText(percent);



    }

    dailyUsageTextView.setText(dailyString);
    totalUsageTextView.setText(totalString);    
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Am I converting my data types wrong?

Comment: How are `series1Numbers` and `series2Numbers` defined? What types are they? Why are you using `Integer`, `Number`, and `Double` instead of just `int` and `double`? You say you cannot multiply or divide the value. What happens when you try? Do you get a compilation error? A run-time error? If so, what error do you get?

Comment: I'd like to second David's question here-  except for in generics, there's almost no reason to use Integer and Double.  And I don't think I've ever seen Number used before.

Comment: Hi David, I updated my code and I get a NullPointerException value when I try to multiply the 'totalDouble' by anything.

Comment: What is your System.out printing?

Comment: so my guess is your intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted or totalDouble is null. Autoboxing then creates a nullpointerexception when you use it in some calculation. On more reason to use int and double instead of the Integer and Double.

Comment: My System.out is printing the same thing as my value for   'totalString'  . (Example: they are both showing 0.21 correctly when they should). Both my 'intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted' and my 'totalDouble' are not null. But 'totalDouble' appears null when it is multiplied. Is there anyway to keep using Number? Do you have any suggestions on how to better approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this instead:

```
//converting the type Number to type double
double dailyDouble = dailyNumber.doubleValue();
double totalDouble = totalNumber.doubleValue();
```

Now you should be able to manipulate the double values without difficulty.

If you get a null pointer exception on the call to `doubleValue` then you will know that the value in the array was null.   You might want to make the array:

```
double[] series2Numbers = new double[ {arraysize} ];
```

Using an array of values instead of array of objects you will always have a value, and never a null pointer.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception on those two lines of code. What does that mean? What should I change?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I changed everything over to double and initialized my seriesArray from being an Integer to a double and it worked!!!! THANKSS :) I wish I had enough reputation to give you an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

By using double values instead of numbers I was able to update the arrays much easier.

```
  //converting the type Number to type double
  double dailyDouble = dailyNumber.doubleValue();
  double totalDouble = totalNumber.doubleValue();


  double[] series2Numbers = new double[ {arraysize} ];
```